# If $ax^2+bx+6=0$ doesn't have $2$ distinct real roots, then find the least value of $ (3a+b)$

Tags: quadratics

If $ax^2+bx+6=0$ doesn't have $2$ distinct real roots, then find the least value of $(3a+b)$
$a,b\in \mathbb R$

Any hint for this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Picking up from $b^2 \leq 24a$, we have $b^2 + 8b \leq 8(3a + b)$ or $$\frac{1}{8}\left( b^2 + 8b \right) \leq 3a + b$$

Now what is the minimum value of the LHS?

Comment: just wanted to confirm, is the min. value -4 ?

Comment: $\frac{1}{8}(b^2 + 8b) = \frac{1}{8}(b+4)^2 - 2$ hence the minimum is $-2$.

Comment: got it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

HINT:
What happens when $D=b^2-4ac>0$ and what happens when $D=0$ and $D<0$

Comment: Iknow that, but I'm unable to use: b^2-24a<=0