# Finding the values of $5a+b$ if $ax^2+bx+10$ does not have $2$ distinct roots

Tags: quadratics

If $ax^2+bx+10=0$ does not have two distinct real roots where( $a$ and $b$ are real) then the possible values of $5a+b$ from the given 4 options(as obviously there can be infinite possible values..but I only need to find out which of the four given possible values is one of these ...in short it is a Multi choice-multi-correct question)  are-( there can be more than one option correct)

1) -3

2) -2

3) -1

4) 0

**my attempt**
Here are some conclusions I have drawn-

- it is given that it does not have two distinct real roots so either( both roots are imaginary and conjugates of each other)- $D(b^2-4ac)<0$ (that is as $c=10$ so $b^2-40a<0$...or another case is both roots become equal that is $b^2-40a=0$.
- also I tried some manipulations like subtracting $f(3)-f(2)$ to get $5a+b$ ....now I think since it is given that the equation does not have two distinct real roots so $f(3)-f(2)$ or $5a+b$ cannot be equal to zero unless both $f(3),f(2)$ become equal to zero..which is not allowed (as real roots should not be distinct)so I think option (D) or zero shouldnt be possible but the answers given are $-2,-1,0$ (**Edit**:*apparently $0$ is not the answer as pointed out be Tim phan below..but I still need help in proving it is equal to $-1,-2$*)....also I am unable to get other answers I have tried getting $5a+b$ by keeping $x=5$ to get $5(5a+b+2)$ but I don't know whether it will be equal to zero or less than or greater than zero... As I don't know whether $5$ is a root of $f(x)$ or not..neither it is given in question...

Any help??

Comment: I think you need more constrains. Here is why. Like you pointed out, essentially, you are solving a system of 2 equations with 3 unknown. $b^2 - 4 a c < 0$ and $b + 5a = N$.

Comment: In the attempted solution, you refer to $b^-40c$. Did you omit saying that $c=10$? Are $a,b,c$ restricted in some way, say to integers?

Comment: If that is the case, then you can try going about it in this way. Assume $b + 5a = 0$, then $b = -5a$ and $a = -\frac{1}{5}b$. Also, we have that $b^2 < 4ac$. Combine these together you will get two equations: $b^2 < -\frac{4}{5}b c$ and $25a^2 < 4a c$. You then proceed with 4 cases $a,b>0$, $a,b<0$, $a>0,b<0$, $a<0,b>0$. If all of them lead to contradiction, then it is not possible.

Comment: Why didn't you write $ax^2+bx+10$, instead of "$c$". Tbh, it looks like you were attempting to make it confusing.

Comment: Let $a=1$ and $b=1.01, 1.02, 1.03, 1.04,\dots$. Don't have distinct real roots, indeed don't have real roots at all.

Comment: @André Nicolas I am not able to get what you are trying to say..can you please explain it a little bit..as you said $a=1$ and let me take $b=1.01$ then the equation has imaginary roots(conjugate to each other) ...OK so what now??..I have already written in question there is a possibility of imaginary roots..but not necessarily... As I think roots can also be equal ..which will give equal real roots...can you please expand this comment a little bit??

Comment: Using the template I mentioned, we can find infinitely many values of $5a+b$ such that $ax^2+bx+10$ does not have distinct real roots. There is something wrong with the question, it has not been fully stated.

Comment: @André Nicolas ...yes...that is the question is asking what are the *possible values of $5a+b$ and 4 options are given*...so we just need to write which values from the 4 options can be equal to $5a+b$ so we are not required to tell all the values of $5a+b$ but just find out which option ***can be equal to 5a+b***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you write $5a + b = k$ and use this to get rid of the $a$ in the equation $b^2 - 40a \leq 0$, you get:

$$b^2 - 40\left(\frac{k - b}{5}\right) \leq 0$$

$$b^2 + 8b \leq 8k$$

Complete the square:

$$(b + 4)^2 \leq 8k + 16$$

$$(b + 4)^2 \leq 8(k + 2)$$

Since $b$ is arbitrary, the only restriction is that the left hand side is nonnegative. So you get:

$$0 \leq 8(k + 2)$$

$$-2 \leq k$$

Hence $k = 0, -1, -2$ are all possible.

Answer (score 1):

The possible values (from those listed) are $0$, $-1$, and $-2$, obtained by $(a,b) = (0,0)$, $(1,-6)$, and $\left(\frac{2}{5},-4\right)$. (The first two are not unique, but the third one is; see below.)

Now, if $ax^2+bx+10$ does not have 2 distinct roots, then the discriminant is nonpositive, i.e. $b^2-40a\le 0$. Hence, $40a\ge b^2$, necessarily implying that $a\ge 0$. Furthermore, 
$$b^2\le 40a\implies |b|\le\sqrt{40a}\implies b\ge -\sqrt{40a}$$
and hence $5a+b \ge 5a-\sqrt{40a}$. It can be checked that
$$\min\limits_{a\ge 0}{\left(5a-\sqrt{40a}\right)} = -2 $$
achieved at $a = \frac{2}{5}$. Hence, if $ax^2+bx+10$ does not have 2 distinct roots, then
$$5a+b\ge -2$$
with equality if and only if $a = \frac{2}{5}$ and $b = -\sqrt{40a} = -4$.

Comment: Why is this reasoning of my wrong....I tried some manipulations like subtracting $f(3)-f(2)$ to get $5a+b$ ....now I think since it is given that the equation does not have two distinct real roots so $f(3)-f(2)$ or $5a+b$ cannot be equal to zero unless both $f(3),f(2)$ become equal to zero..which is not allowed (as real roots should not be distinct)so I think option (D) or zero shouldnt be possible

Comment: @Freelancer why can't we have $f(3)-f(2) = 0$? For example, if $f$ is constant, then this is true, and there's nothing saying it can't (since if it were constant, it would take the constant value $10$, which is nonzero)

Comment: I think since it is given that the equation does not have two distinct real roots so $f(3)-f(2)$ or $5a+b$ cannot be equal to zero unless both $f(3),f(2)$ become equal to zero..(which can be only possible when both 3,2 are roots are of the equation...which is not allowed (as real roots should not be distinct here)

Comment: @Freelancer who cares if $f$ doesn't have two distinct roots? It says very little about the difference between its values. For example, $f(x) = x^2+1$ has no real roots, yet $f(1) - f(-1) = 0$, $f(2)-f(-2) = 0$, $f(3) - f(-3)=0$, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Assume $b + 5a = 0$, then $b = -5a$ and $a = -\frac{1}{5}b$. Also, we have that $b^2 < 4ac$. Combine these together to obtain $b^2 < -\frac{4}{5}b c$ and $25a^2 < 4a c$.

(1) If $a>0, b>0$, then we have: $b<-\frac{4}{5}c$< which implies $c<0$. False.

(2) If $a<0, b<0$, then we have: $-25|a|>4c$ which implies $c<0$. False.

If $a>0, b<0$, you have the same thing as in (1) and if If $a<0, b>0$, you have the same thing as in (2). Thus it is not possible for $b + 5a = 0$.
Proceed similarly.

---

**Second part**:
let $D>0$, assume $5a + b =-D$, so $b = -(D+5a)$. Then for this equation to not have two distinct real roots: $b^2 \leq 40a$. replacing $a$ in to obtain:
$ (D+5a)^2 < 40a$ Notice that this implies $a > 0$. Simplify:
$$D + 5a < \pm\sqrt{40 a}$$
Let $u = \sqrt{a}$, then we have $5u^2 \mp \sqrt{40}u + D < 0$ is the condition, ***which is if we can find such $u$ under some condition on $D$, then the same condition is also the condition for $ax^2 + bx + 10 = 0$ to not have two distinct real roots.***
Solve this to get 
$$u=\frac{1}{10}\left(\sqrt{40} - \sqrt{40 - 20 D}\right)$$
this has a solution if $D \leq 2$, which means if $D \leq 2$, then the $ax^2 + bx + 10 = 0$ does not have two distinct real roots. Thus the possible solutions are $5a + b = -1, -2$, or (3) and (2).
Please check my algebra carefully.

Comment: You can't do that yet, since you do not know if $a$ is positive or negative, which can affect the inequality sign.

Comment: I edit the second part there. Check the algebra carefully though. Not super logical, but it is one way of doing that.

Comment: You're right. I just fixed it.

Comment: Also how can we assume $5a+b=-D$ ??

Comment: Oh..is $D$ in your equation discriminant here??

Comment: It's just scratch work. So what I did was trying to find the condition assuming what we should have.

Comment: D is just a positive real number that is used to generalize this problem. It can be restated like this: for what value of $D$ in the equation $5a + b = -D$, does the equation $ax^2 + bx + 10 = 0$ has no real distinct root?

Comment: Ok..so $D$ is any general number which may or may not be the discriminant ..right??

Comment: Yes. In fact, it should not be the discriminant. Sorry for using such a confusing notation. :(

Comment: Oh..yes thank you...I think I got it...after reading this I think I also understood a little bit of this very similar question...but its solution is very short...and I was not able to use it...here ..do you mind taking a look at it. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1046531/if-ax2bx6-0-doesnt-have-2-distinct-real-roots-then-find-the-least-value

Comment: Yes, it uses the same reasoning.

Comment: $D\le 2$ actually means $D = -1$ or $D=-2$. Also, how does $a>0,b<0$ give the same thing as in (1)?

Comment: Yup, just fix. Thanks a lot. Since you really only need the inequality resulted from $a>0$, that is $b$ does not matter as long as $a>0$.

Comment: To get (1), it seems like you went from the inequality $b^2 < -\frac{4}{5}bc$ to $b < -\frac{4}{5}c$. This assumes that $b>0$.

Comment: So after all this don't you think @Tim phan you should edit your answer to say that $a+5b$ can be equal to zero...

Answer (score 0):

I found that if a = 1/5 and b = -1 then 5a+b = 0. 
Did i break any rules?

Comment: You found one solution ! Are there others ?